# How to access Lady Liberty Island

Tags: lego-city-undercover

I have completed the main story of the game and I'm traversing the city for collectables, but whenever I come close to Lady Liberty Island the game tells me it's closed to the public. Personally, I wouldn't try to keep out a police officer but this city somehow does.

What do I need to unlock to access Lady Liberty Island? A specific character (like superstrength) or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to have completed the game and have Rex Fury equipped as your Robber disguise. (It's 1,000,000 studs in the shop, unlocked automatically at the end of the final special assignment.)

In the Downtown area, look for the round fortress with planters spaced around the walls. Enter over the roofs or by the entrance cut into the wall nearest the waterfront. In the center of the fortress, there is a crate with an orange handle. Use Rex Fury to pull it apart, then build the green Mario pipe inside. Stand on top of the pipe and press A to unlock the island, after which you can build a ferry point at the dock on the island to make it accessible via Crescent Park.

answer found at:

http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii-u/632938-lego-city-undercover/answers/348407-when-does-lady-liberty-island-become-open-to-the-public